# How to manage IP blocks assigned to organisation by regional internet registry

Tags: ip

Our company has been assigned a block of IPs by APNIC. We did not have ASN though since we plan to use all IPs for our servers collocated in our current hosting provider.

My question is: Is is common for a hosting provider (ISP) to accept our IPs in their network? and if so, what do they or we have to do to have the IPs assigned to their network?

I have a little networking knowledge. Please share a link or a book if the answer is too long to share here.

Thanks.

P/s: we need our own IPs since our company is providing email marketing service, thus we want our reputation is exclusive.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what the ISP is willing to do for you, but technically it's possible. Either by adding your IP-space to their ASN and announcing it that way to the rest of the internet, or by setting up a BGP session with your equipment, accepting the IP-space from your ASN, which can be either public or private.

Comment: Thanks Teun. I understand the basic that my IPs will need to be with some AS. When my ISP agrees, do I have to ask RIR to assign the IP block to the ISP's ASN ?

Comment: The exact rules may depend on the RIR. In RIPE world (which I'm familiair with) the owner of the IP-block allows the ISP to route the prefix by creating a `mnt-routes` entry on the object in the database, so the ISP can create the appropriate route-object linking the prefix to their ASN. You mentioned ARIN in your original question, I have no experiences there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you will need to get your own ASN.  Then you will advertise your IP block to the hosting provider.  Usually this is done via BGP, but it is up to your ISP.

I'm sure ISP can help you set this up.  They do this kind of thing all day long.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Since we just need a exclusive IP block, we rely all on the hosting provider for networking, thus no need to implement an AS.